# Is it worth using VCS (Version Control Softwares) for hobbystic/small/personal projects?

Tags: programming-practices, version-control

The question is fairly self-explainatory.

Is it worth using VCS (Version Control Softwares) for hobbystic/small/personal projects?

Comment: No, you probably shouldn't be using CVS, as the world has moved on and that software isn't being maintained any longer. You might want to look into newer version control systems like *Subversion* (fairly similar, as it's centralized too) or *Git* (distributed, feels more lightweight, but has a long learning curve). I personally use Git for any project that has it's own folder, no matter how small.

Comment: By CVS I did not specify which software but _only_ the control versioning practice of doing so.

Comment: [CVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) is a specific [version control software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you mean the type of software that RCS, CVS and SVN belong to you may wish to refer to "VCS" which stands for Version Control Software.  CVS itself is a specific implementation of this concept.

Comment: I've fixed the title.

Comment: wow such confusion with cvs ;-) personally even for a single text file I don't bother wondering if I should. Create a directory, git init, git add, git commit. And there you go, this way you will never hesitate to cleanup and move around stuff instead of messy commented code.

Comment: @vincent back in the days I used RCS (those days, CVS was just shell scripts that called RCS).  A similar process, though all you had to do is create a subdirectory "RCS" and you were done.  I admit that I still do keep my .files in RCS even today.

Comment: The reason so many people respond to CVS by suggesting SVN (subversion) is that SVN was specifically designed to act as a replacement for CVS; the design goal for SVN was basically, "be like CVS, but better!" Most people agree that this goal was met.  See also [Subversion vs CVS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/245290/18192).

Comment: @MichaelT used it as well, but wouldn't go back. But for sure it was so easy to setup that on that aspect, any vcs that doesn't allow fast local versioning is a regression.

Comment: Just an FYI, but both mercurial and bazaar  are similar to git in their support for easy-to-use local repositories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is worth using a [Version Control System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)/[Software Configuration Management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) such as CVS, git, mercurial, subversion, etc.  If you don't use a true version control system, you'll probably end up creating your own ad-hoc system with folders or zip files, and it won't be nearly as capable, efficient, or as easy to use as a commercial or open-source version control system.

You originally mentioned CVS, but that may not be the best fit.  It's old and it's designed to be installed on a central server (though you can just install it locally).  Although it has branching and tagging and merging, it doesn't always do a good job.  You would probably be better served by a modern distributed version control system like git or mercurial.  And although you can technically use any version control system, you can work a lot more smoothly if you choose one that is well-supported by the other tools in your toolchain.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that people without any vcs tend to create backup files manually. It's quickly a mess.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's worth using, but for different reasons than are typical on large shared projects:

- You might have long gaps where you don't work on a personal project.  Having the history makes it easier to see where you left off.
- It makes it easier to experiment and get back to a known good point if it doesn't work.  On personal projects I do this much more often than at work, where I usually don't have the luxury of spending time on a concept that doesn't work.
- It makes it easy to sync between different environments, say a laptop and a desktop.
- You can easily get a [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) account or similar and have a backup of all your work, together with an issue tracker that helps you keep track of what you wanted to do next.
- It makes it easier to answer questions like, "Have I really removed all the debug code I don't need anymore?" or "What have I changed since this part last worked?"

Answer (score 2):

No, you probably shouldn't be using CVS, as the world has moved on and that software isn't being maintained any longer.

You might want to look into newer version control systems like [*Subversion*](https://subversion.apache.org/) (fairly similar to CVS, as both are centralized) or [*Git*](http://git-scm.com/) (distributed, feels more lightweight, but has a long learning curve). I personally use Git for any project that has it's own folder, no matter how small: Creating a new repo is an incredibly cheap and easy operation and has no real downsides.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You don't know when a project will become something much bigger or when you'll want to go back in time. Also, it's good practice.

On the other hand if you are just doing very small things, like tutorials or things you doubt you will be using a week from now, I say "why bother?".